# How can I capture drag and drop from the other application

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, capture

I searched through the answers to various questions, but I think that this one hasn't been discussed yet. There are two winforms applications one has focus and the other is running, but does not have focus.

How can I capture from the not foucused one what is happening in the focused. In particulary I need to capture the coordinates from start and end of drag and drop.

The app in the background has a database and I want the user to work kind of simultaneously with two apps. In one app the user does drag and drop and the other app captures coordinates and based on that searches the database and displays results. The user however still remains with the focus in the first one.

Any help with the C# code will be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You describe two separate App's, so my response assumes you have two distinct Processes (EXE's) running. If that's the case, then you need to use an InterProcess Communication Mechanism, [consider Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx).

Answer (score -3):

The Drag/Drop functions take care of that for you. Just get them setup and running, it'll work between the apps automatically. 
I do it all the time, forget about the other guy.

Comment: You do not seem to have read the question well. The OP is not asking about dragging from app1 *to* app2; he's asking about dragging completely within app1 and having app2 get info about that, *without ever getting focus* (thereby implying it is not the one being dropped on)

Comment: still ignore the other guy, it's a Copy/Paste hook which is what Drag/Drop really is, i'll paste a partial answer in a few, i'm missing one piece.

Comment: Where do you get Copy/Paste from the question? The OP is asking about **capturing the coordinates** of the drag/drops. Copy/Paste isn't remotely related.

Comment: `i'll paste a partial answer in a few, i'm missing one piece`  Asking question for answering another question? Nice...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785526/sendmessage-to-copy-cut-paste-wm-copydata-0x004a