# SendMessage() to copy/cut/paste WM_COPYDATA 0x004A

Tags: c#

I've been browsing and it's unclear to me **how to simply send in the Ctrl+x or Ctrl+c command** *to copy/cut data(strings)*, but I'm pretty sure this is the pInvoke needed.  A quick hand, anyone?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

possibly along with this: 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetClipboardData(uint uFormat, IntPtr hMem);

not sure how to use either of these correctly, please help.

```
IntPtr nextClipboardAppWindow;
public frmMain()
{
        nextClipboardAppWindow = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int)this.Handle);
}

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        // defined in winuser.h
        const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
        const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                //DisplayClipboardData();
                SendMessage(nextClipboardAppWindow, m.Msg, m.WParam,
                            m.LParam);
                break;

            case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                if (m.WParam == nextClipboardAppWindow)
                    nextClipboardAppWindow = m.LParam;
                else
                    SendMessage(nextClipboardAppWindow, m.Msg, m.WParam,
                                m.LParam);
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: **who**, _what_, @where, ____when____, "why", but mostly: How ?...

Comment: If you simply want the answer there is no one to help you out.You need to be very specific while asking a question. -1 for that.

Comment: Is there an admin on here that sees this? can they laugh once for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net and have access to `System.Windows.Forms` then you can use `Clipboard` class to `Set` or `Get` clipboard data.
Here is the link to MSDN with example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx

`Clipboard` class actually posts data to System clipboard. It is not bound to application. It is simple as

`System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText("This will be available across all applications");`

Comment: i need to copy something outside of the app itself how do you Clipboard.SetDataObject(object data, bool copy); for outside the form?

Comment: `Clipboard` class copy/paste is not bound to application. It sets/gets value to/from system clipboard. I have updated my answer so have a look.